# Getting null after updating the state in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm building a drag-and-drop web app using reactjs. The issue I'm facing is when I start the drag, it fires the `handleDragStart` function to update the `selectedCard` state variable, but when I try to access this variable(selectedCard) inside the `handleDrop` function, it logs `null` in the console.

My question is how I can get access to the `selectedCard` variable inside the `handleDrop` function?

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-sun-4us8uy?file=/src/index.js

My Code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Panel = ({ data }) => {
  const { title, label, items } = data;
  const [selectedCard, setSelectedCard] = useState(null);

  const handleDragStart = (item) => {
    setSelectedCard(item);
  };
  const handleDrop = (colName, id) => {
    console.log(selectedCard);
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-56">
      <h2 className="mb-4">{title}</h2>
      <ul className="flex flex-col space-y-4">
        {items.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <button
              id={item.id}
              className="px-4 py-2 border w-full text-left cursor-grab"
              onDragStart={() => handleDragStart(item)}
              onDrop={() => handleDrop(label, item.id)}
              onDragOver={handleDragOver}
              draggable
            >
              {item.name}
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Panel;
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, works fine https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-pateu-6rlrw4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: try this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-sun-4us8uy?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are dragging the item from one component to the other, since every component has it's own isolated state it cannot know what the selectedCard property's value is in the other component. If you want to get the value of the item that your are dragging into the other component you will have to provide the value to the function given.
Also for your instance you want to use `onDragEnd` because otherwise the event will be triggered on the element that your are dragging the item to instead of triggering the event on the dragged element, you can use something like this:

```js
onDragEnd={() => handleDragEnd(label, item)}
```

**Addition after comments**

For tracking where the card moves from one component to the other I would advise using the parent component by emitting what card you want to move on the `onDragStart` to the parent and the by using the `onDrop` to let the parent know where you dropped the card. From these two the parent component can figure out what card should be moved where and be able to update the state accordingly to display the changes.
In the example you gave you can do this by

```js
function App() {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(COLUMNS);

  const [draggedCard, setDraggedCard] = useState(null);
  const [fromLabel, setFromLabel] = useState('');


  handleDragStart(card, label) {
    setDraggedCard(card);
    setFromLabel(label);
  }

  handleDrop(label) {
    // Logic to remove card from starting label and add in to the list that is given as a parameter to this function
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {COLUMNS.map((column) => (
        <Panel 
          key={column.label} 
          data={column} 
          handleDragStart={handleDragStart} 
          handleDrop={handleDrop}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in this case, I still don't get access to the selectedCard in the `handleDrop` function.

Comment: I need access to the `selectedCard` variable in the `handleDrop` function so I can remove it from the old column and add it to the new column. I think I can only access the new column(label) value in the `handleDrop` function, not in the `handleDragEnd` function. Any idea how should I handle this?

Comment: I think the best way to handle this is to emit an event to the parent component in this case the `App.js` in the `onDragStart` and then using the `onDrop` in the component you are dragging it to to let the parent know where you drag it to and then update the state in the parent to reflect what you did, since changing the state in the parent will also change the children, do you get what i mean?

Comment: And then tracking which card you are dragging in the parent and on drop moving it to the appropriate list

Comment: Could you please write it as answer? It would be helpful for others as well!

Comment: Is what I added sufficient for you to resolve your issue?